# Wrapper for std::vector that makes Structure of Arrays look like Array of Structures

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a vector of a struct with 8 different fields (integers and pointers) that serves as a database for my program. Usually only a few of these fields are actually used (often just one). It was fine originally, but now it's running out of memory when storing billions of elements. I want to store this data sparsely without having zero/null entries for the unused fields in each object. However, this is used all over the place in the codebase and is difficult to change.

I decided to store the individual fields as separate vectors and create a class that wraps these vectors, making a SoA appear as an AoS to the callers. The set of fields that are used is known at runtime during creation of the database. It needs to have a large number of std::vector member functions. The best I was able to come up with was some macros and lots of copy-paste lines of code to handle the individual field vectors:

```
#define SELECT_FIELD_VECT(FUNC) (use_uv() ? uv.FUNC : (use_dv() ? dv.FUNC : (use_sv() ? sv.FUNC : rv.FUNC)))
#define APPLY_FIELD_VECT(FUNC) { if(use_uv()) {uv.FUNC;} if(use_dv()) {dv.FUNC;} if(use_sv()) {sv.FUNC;} if(use_rv()) {rv.FUNC;} }

class md_tracker_t {
  vector< match_track_data_uints_t > uv;
  vector< delta_pair  const * > dv;
  vector< std::string const * > sv, rv;
public:
  bool  empty( void ) const { return SELECT_FIELD_VECT(empty()); }
  size_t size( void ) const { return SELECT_FIELD_VECT(size ()); }
  size_t capacity( void ) const { return SELECT_FIELD_VECT(capacity()); }
  void  clear( void ) { uv.clear(); dv.clear(); sv.clear(); rv.clear(); }
  void shrink_to_fit( void ) { APPLY_FIELD_VECT(shrink_to_fit()); }
  void reserve( size_t const sz ) { APPLY_FIELD_VECT(reserve(sz)); }
  void resize ( size_t const sz ) { APPLY_FIELD_VECT(resize(sz)); }
  void swap( md_tracker_t &mt ) { uv.swap( mt.uv ); dv.swap( mt.dv ); sv.swap( mt.sv ); rv.swap( mt.rv ); }
  void push_back( match_track_data_t const &md ) {
    if( use_uv() ) { uv.push_back( md.uints ); }
    if( use_dv() ) { dv.push_back( md.deltas ); }
    if( use_sv() ) { sv.push_back( md.signature ); }
    if( use_rv() ) { rv.push_back( md.rulename ); }
  }
  void copy_from( size_t const from_ix, size_t const to_ix ) {
    if( use_uv() ) { uv[to_ix] = uv[from_ix]; }
    if( use_dv() ) { dv[to_ix] = dv[from_ix]; }
    if( use_sv() ) { sv[to_ix] = sv[from_ix]; }
    if( use_rv() ) { rv[to_ix] = rv[from_ix]; }
  }
  void add_from( md_tracker_t const &mt, size_t const ix ) {
    if( use_uv() ) { uv.push_back( mt.uv[ix] ); }
    if( use_dv() ) { dv.push_back( mt.dv[ix] ); }
    if( use_sv() ) { sv.push_back( mt.sv[ix] ); }
    if( use_rv() ) { rv.push_back( mt.rv[ix] ); }
  }
  match_track_data_t get_mtd( size_t const ix ) const {
    assert( ix < size() );
    return match_track_data_t( ( use_uv() ? uv[ix] : match_track_data_uints_t() ),
                   ( use_dv() ? dv[ix] : 0 ),
                   ( use_sv() ? sv[ix] : 0 ),
                   ( use_rv() ? rv[ix] : 0 ) );
  }
  ...
};
```

This works, but it's messy. It also only uses 4 of the 8 fields. I would like to add more fields later without having to change dozens of lines of code for each field. Is there a more compact/clean way to do this? Some magic with macros, templates, C++11, etc? Thank you.

Comment: Is there some reason you're not using an actual, well, database? This is kind of a solved problem.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I also agree with him. You just should use a database which is already well optimized for functions like sorting.  I don't think there is a way that for each entity in your array is defined somewhat different. You maybe (?) could use polymorphism, creating different objects with different number of fields and push them all together into a vector, but it is a long and very dirty way of doing this. The solution is using a database ..

Comment: [SqlLite comes to mind](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html).

Comment: You can try wrapping something like `std::vector<std::vector<std::variant<Field1, Field2, ..., FieldN>>>` in an accessor class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We've tried using sqlite for other purposes but it just doesn't scale to billions of elements. The performance is terrible, and it takes too much disk space. If you can recommend something in-memory that does scale then I can take a look.

Comment: std::variant would work for one field but not multiple fields. But we're using gcc-6.3, which doesn't have C++17 features such as std::variant.

Comment: You _could_ use a variadic template and make a neat-looking shim, but it would take a lot work to verify that it's a zero-cost abstraction (and if it's not, what's the point of using a cache-friendly structure of arrays?). At 8 elements, I'd just extend your current structure and keep using the fields and methods you're used to. Any bigger, and you should consider a database not so much for absolute efficiency than for resiliance (at that scale, you should worry about losing data in exceptional cases).

Comment: This is a buffer that passes data between two computation stages of a single process. It's all in memory and not written to disk/persistent, so there should be no data loss. The only requirement is that it fits in system memory. Each data element is written once and typically read only a few times.

Comment: _"The performance is terrible, and it takes too much disk space"_ With respect, it sounds like you used it wrong. I'm not saying you need to use SQLite specifically (I'd actually recommend something stronger like Postgres) but the scale you're talking about is pretty commonplace for a database and your report about its performance is unusual. Given the way you're trying to arrange your data in this app (and the way you've arranged it in the past), I suggest studying more about data storage from a good book before trying to use _any_ particular technology for implementation.

Comment: I think the key is that, at the point you find yourself with such a load of hackery that indeed let you to ask this question, you probably already know you need to fundamentally revisit the approach.

Comment: It was actually a different group that wrote a sqlite database (I believe it was postgres). It was for a somewhat different application, and it didn't scale well beyond 100M elements. In this case I have 70B elements in the smaller example and we estimate 800B in the large example. There are 40 threads writing to the front and 40 threads reading from the back, but the buffer size grows to 16B elements in the middle which is too much memory. The runtime is okay, > 1GB/s for copies to/from the buffer, which is close to disk rate. I'm not sure a database can do that.

Comment: For now I was just trying to find a cleaner way to store the data for the serial part that does the copies. I got in down to a vector wrapper. I don't want to replace the whole system. It works now, it's just a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the little enable bits you have (`use_uv()`, etc) are interesting and I'm pretty sure there's not a generic version of a similar function, so I gave it a go.

To make the data generic, you have to replace the "struct" part and those lovely field names with the indices of an `std::tuple`, the generic struct. You can make up for it by extending `std::tuple` to add accessors

```cpp
struct match_track_data_t : std::tuple<match_track_data_uints_t, delta_pair, std::string, std::string> {
  using std::tuple<match_track_data_uints_t, delta_pair, std::string, std::string>::tuple;
  match_track_data_uints_t& uv() { return std::get<0>(*this); }
  match_track_data_uints_t& uv() const { return std::get<0>(*this); }
  delta_pair& dv() { return std::get<1>(*this); }
  delta_pair& dv() const { return std::get<1>(*this); }
  /* etc... */
};
```

For the vector, the data because a tuple of vectors. The `use_*` flags become an array of predicates:

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
class md_tracker_t {
  std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...> data;
  std::array<bool(*)(), sizeof...(Ts)> use_ix;

public:
  md_tracker_t(std::array<bool(*)(), sizeof...(Ts)> use_ix) : use_ix(use_ix) { }
```

Now, I tried to classify each method in your class as some generic action:

- `select` - does something with the first enabled vector and returns the value
- `apply` - does something to each enabled vector (or all vectors)
- `apply_join` - zips the tuple with some other tuple, and does something to each enabled pair
- `get_mtd` - this function I couldn't mash into the other types

The `apply*` functions should have a version that applies it only to enabled arrays, or all arrays.

If you map the entire public interface to those generic functions:

```
  bool empty() const { return select([](auto& v) { return v.empty(); }); }
  bool size() const { return select([](auto& v) { return v.size(); }); }
  bool capacity() const { return select([](auto& v) { return v.capacity(); }); }
  void clear() { apply<false>([](auto& v) { v.clear(); }); }
  void shrink_to_fit() { apply([](auto& v) { v.shrink_to_fit(); }); }
  void reserve( size_t const sz ) { return apply([&sz](auto& v) { v.reserve(sz); }); }
  void resize ( size_t const sz ) { return apply([&sz](auto& v) { v.resize(sz); }); }
  void swap( md_tracker_t &mt ) { apply_join<false>(mt, [](auto& v, auto& w) { v.swap(w); }); }
  void push_back( std::tuple<Ts...> const &md ) { apply_join(md, [](auto& v, auto& e) { v.push_back(e); }); }
  void copy_from( size_t const from_ix, size_t const to_ix ) { apply([&from_ix, &to_ix](auto& v) { v[to_ix] = v[from_ix]; }); }
  void add_from( md_tracker_t const &mt, size_t const ix ) { apply_join(mt, [&ix](auto& v, auto& w) { v.push_back(w[ix]); }); }
  std::tuple<Ts...> get_mtd( size_t const ix ) const { return get_mtd_impl(ix, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}); }
```

All you have to do is implement them! (I'm skipping a lot of boilerplate here by using C++14 generic lambdas).

To implement `select`, you can't just write a loop because `std::tuple` can only be indexed with a *compile time* argument. So you have to go recursive instead: start at zero, and if [0] is enabled, apply the lambda to that vector OR repeat for the next index:

```
  template <typename Functor, size_t Index = 0, typename std::enable_if<Index != sizeof...(Ts)>::type* = nullptr>
  decltype(auto) select(Functor&& functor) const {
    return use_ix[Index]() 
      ? functor(std::get<Index>(data))
      : select<Functor, Index + 1>(std::forward<Functor>(functor));
  }

  template <typename Functor, size_t Index, typename std::enable_if<Index == sizeof...(Ts)>::type* = nullptr>
  decltype(auto) select(Functor&& functor) const  { return decltype(functor(std::get<0>(data))){}; }
```

`apply` is a little simpler, because you can just expand the entire tuple with `std::index_sequence` and `std::get` into a throwaway boolean array. The comma operator (always returns the right hand side) is kind of a cheat code to turn a void function into an expression:

```cpp
  template <bool conditional = true, typename Functor, size_t... Is>
  void apply(Functor&& functor, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    std::initializer_list<bool> { (!conditional || use_ix[Is]() ? (functor(std::get<Is>(data)), false) : false)... };
  }

  template <bool conditional, typename Functor>
  void apply(Functor&& functor) {
    return apply(std::forward<Functor>(functor), std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{});
  }
```

The boolean `conditional` template argument is basically an override. If `false`, it will apply the lambda no matter what the predicate returns.

A lot of functions, like `push_back` and `swap` take either a slice or another SoA and cross-join it. For those, we have `apply_join`, which is almost the same as `apply` except it handles the extra argument:

```cpp
  template <bool conditional = true, typename Functor, typename Arg, size_t... Is>
  void apply_join(Functor&& functor, Arg& arg, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    std::initializer_list<bool> { (!conditional || use_ix[Is]() ? (functor(std::get<Is>(data), std::get<Is>(arg)), false) : false)... };
  }

  template <bool conditional = true, typename Functor, typename Arg>
  void apply_join(Functor&& functor, Arg& arg) {
    return apply_join(std::forward<Functor>(functor), arg, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{});
  }
```

Finally, `get_mtd` just expands the tuple, applies the index operator to each one, then passes it to an `std::tuple`:

```cpp
  template <size_t... Is>
  std::tuple<Ts...> get_mtd_impl( size_t const ix, std::index_sequence<Is...>) const {
    assert(ix < sizeof...(Ts));
    return std::tuple<Ts...>(std::get<Is>(data)[ix]...);
  }
```

And that's it!

```cpp
};
```

Possibly more code than if you just did it by hand, but you can add fields all day without unnecessary boilerplate.

Usage:

```cpp
using md_tracker = md_tracker_t<match_track_data_uints_t, delta_pair, std::string, std::string>;
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/p5t6wu

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put this together. I think this is the correct approach, though it's more complex than I expected and I'm not sure I fully understand how it works. It doesn't compile in gcc-5.4 but seems to work in gcc-6.3 if I use -std=c++14. Not sure if I can change that for this project. I don't know if this is going to work because I need something default constructable, copyable, and (maybe?) serializable. I think I would need to convert the tuple returned by get_mtd() back into the original struct.

Comment: For testing I renamed md_tracker_t to md_tracker_template_t and added this: typedef md_tracker_template_t< match_track_data_uints_t, delta_pair const*, std::string const*, std::string const*, std::string const* > md_tracker_t;

Comment: But that gives me the error: error: no matching function for call to 'croix::md_tracker_template_t<croix::match_track_data_uints_t, const croix::delta_pair*, const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*>::md_tracker_template_t()'

Comment: This class is used in almost a hundred places in the codebase and it's difficult to even experiment with if I have to modify all of the users. The subset of fields that need to be tracked are known at runtime and will sometimes change for the same match_track_data_t as they're reused for multiple purposes. They can't be specified in the class definition. I could change to shared_ptr<> but of what type? Changing to pointer requires changing hundreds of "." to "->". Wish I had figured this out before using it in some many places!

Comment: Hi @FrankGennari, thanks for the details. I totally agree with you that making it generic was a lot more complicated than it seemed up front! We can make it C++11 friendly, but you would have to replace all those convenient lambdas with structs so it would add even more boilerplate. You might also have to add some replacements for things like `std::index_sequence`, even though it's only a few lines of code to add.

Comment: @FrankGennari (cont'd). As for `croix::md_tracker_t`, you might try adding implicit casts between `std::tuple<...>` and `md_tracker_t`. That would mean adding a constructor for `md_tracker_t` that accepts the appropriate `std::tuple<>`, and an implicit cast operator overload that converts it back to a tuple: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator . That would mean you have to update the conversion functions when you add or remove fields, but at least you don't have to modify so many methods.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll just keep my original version for now since it seems to be working. Maybe later when we move to a new gcc version I can revisit this. It's good to know that it can be done this way.

Answer (score 0):

Intel have created a template library for this exact purpose.
See [SDLT (SIMD Data Layout Templates)](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/libraries/introduction-to-the-simd-data-layout-templates.html)

> SIMD Data Layout Templates (SDLT) is a C++11 template library
> providing containers that represent arrays of "Plain Old Data" objects
> (a struct whose data members do not have any pointers/references and
> no virtual functions) using layouts that enable generation of
> efficient SIMD (single instruction multiple data) vector code.

> SDLT uses standard ISO C++11 code. It does not require a special language
> or compiler to be functional, but takes advantage of performance
> features (such as OpenMP* SIMD extensions and pragma ivdep ) that may
> not be available to all compilers. It is designed to promote scalable
> SIMD vector programming. To use the library, specify SIMD loops and
> data layouts using explicit vector programming model and SDLT
> containers, and let the compiler generate efficient SIMD code in an
> efficient manner. Many of the library interfaces employ generic
> programming, in which interfaces are defined by requirements on types
> and not specific types. The C++ Standard Template Library (STL) is an
> example of generic programming. Generic programming enables SDLT to be
> flexible yet efficient. The generic interfaces enable you to customize
> components to your specific needs.

> The net result is that SDLT enables you to specify a preferred SIMD data layout far more conveniently than re-structuring your code completely with a new data structure for
> effective vectorization, and at the same time can improve performance.

I have no experience with this myself so would welcome comments from anyone who has tried it.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this works for my application. First, my data is not POD because it contains internal pointers. Second, the problem is related to memory usage and not runtime performance/SIMD. Third, this is for the Intel compiler while we're using gcc.